# Repeated calls to CwiseUnaryView - better to copy to a matrix?

Tags: eigen, eigen3

As the title says, I've got a custom UnaryView function that is getting called multiple times in different operations (mostly multiplication with other matrices). For example:

```
MatrixXd out = mat1.cview() * mat2;
MatrixXd out2 = mat1.cview() * mat3.transpose();
```

Would it be faster to first copy the custom view into a separate matrix and use that instead? For example:

```
MatrixXd mat1_dbl = mat1.cview();
MatrixXd out = mat1_dbl * mat2;
MatrixXd out2 = mat1_dbl * mat3.transpose();
```

Basically, is repeatedly using the UnaryView slower than copying to a matrix and using that instead?

Comment: Did you benchmark it? Did you compile it and checked whether Eigen does that automatically anyways?

Comment: I didn't even think to benchmark, to be honest. That answered my question, sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: You can write this as answer instead of editing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have done my own benchmarking. Google benchmark shows that it is markedly faster to copy first:

```
2019-04-09 20:55:55
Running ./CView
Run on (16 X 4053.06 MHz CPU s)
CPU Caches:
  L1 Data 32K (x8)
  L1 Instruction 64K (x8)
  L2 Unified 512K (x8)
  L3 Unified 8192K (x2)
--------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                 Time           CPU Iterations
--------------------------------------------------------
UnaryView_Repeat  147390919 ns  147385796 ns          5
UnaryView_Copy    139456051 ns  139451409 ns          5
```

Tested with:

```
#include <stan/math/prim/mat/fun/Eigen.hpp>
#include <stan/math/fwd/mat.hpp>
#include <stan/math/fwd/core.hpp>
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>

static void UnaryView_Repeat(benchmark::State& state) {
  using Eigen::MatrixXd;
  using stan::math::matrix_fd;

  matrix_fd m_fd1(1000, 1000);
  m_fd1.val_() = MatrixXd::Random(1000, 1000);
  m_fd1.d_() = MatrixXd::Random(1000, 1000);
  MatrixXd m_d2 = MatrixXd::Random(1000, 1000);


  for (auto _ : state) {
    MatrixXd out(1000,1000);

    out = m_fd1.val_() * m_d2 
            + m_fd1.val_().transpose() * m_d2
            + m_fd1.val_().array().exp().matrix();
  }
}
BENCHMARK(UnaryView_Repeat);

static void UnaryView_Copy(benchmark::State& state) {
  using Eigen::MatrixXd;
  using stan::math::matrix_fd;

  matrix_fd m_fd1(1000, 1000);
  m_fd1.val_() = MatrixXd::Random(1000, 1000);
  m_fd1.d_() = MatrixXd::Random(1000, 1000);
  MatrixXd m_d2 = MatrixXd::Random(1000, 1000);


  for (auto _ : state) {
    MatrixXd out(1000,1000);
    MatrixXd m_fd1_val = m_fd1.val_();

    out = m_fd1_val * m_d2 + m_fd1_val.transpose() * m_d2
            + m_fd1_val.array().exp().matrix();
  }
}
BENCHMARK(UnaryView_Copy);

BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```